# Custom external connectors in apex

Tags: apex

Recently I came across  Apex connector frame work.And I dont have any idea about this.How can we create custom external connectors in apex?

Comment: Here is a slideshare from a dreamforce session from last year going over Odata and the Apex Connector framework: http://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/df13-using-external-objects-for-integration-mt I'll try to see if I can dig up the video from the session, and any other info.

Comment: Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67KIFdKshfs

Comment: @MarkMasterson I have seen this video and I have implemented using OData.But the alternate option Apex connector frame is where i have no idea like how to create my custom external connector.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know that there is a whole lot of info on the topic aside from the demo of the apex connector framework in that video from ~25:44 - 30:44. Perhaps someone else has some insight.

Comment: @Manoj, did you get any details on creating custom connector in Apex ? I cann't even find documentation on the classes and interfaces

Answer (score 1):

The Apex adapter is not GA as of 10JUN15, hence no documentation.

You will have to ask your Account Executive for a nomination (pilot features are made available this way) if you want access to the pre-release feature.

Recap, External Connections on the roadmap:

1) OData 2.0 adapter (GA as of 10JUN15)

2) Salesforce adapter (pilot only as of 10JUN15), intended for SFDC to SFDC.

3) Apex adapter (pilot only as of 10JUN15), intended primarily for web services where re-tooling everything into OData format isn't going to be feasible (cost, dev bandwidth, etc).